# Decode alfresco file name or replace unicode[_x0020_] characters in String/fileName

Tags: java, unicode, alfresco, decode

I am using alfresco download upload services using java.

When I upload the file to alfreco server it gives me the following path :

```
/app:Home/cm:Company_x0020_Home/cm:Abc/cm:TestFile/cm:V4/cm:BC1X_x0020_0400_x0020_0109-_x0028_1-2_x0029__v2.pdf
```

When I use the same file path and download using alfresco services I took the file name at the end of the path

```
i.e    ABC1X_x0020_0400_x0020_0109-_x0028_1-2_x0029__v2.pdf
```

How can I remove or decode the [Unicode] characters in fileName

```
String decoded = URLDecoder.decode(queryString, "UTF-8");
```

The above does not work .

These are some Unicode characters which appeared in my file name.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Please do not mark the question as duplicate as I have searched below links but non of those gave the solution.
Following are the links that I have searched for replacing unicode charectors in String with java.

[Java removing unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020893/java-removing-unicode-characters)

[Remove non-ASCII characters from String in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574289/remove-non-ascii-characters-from-string-in-java)

[How can I replace a unicode character in java string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024609/how-can-i-replace-a-unicode-character-in-java-string)

[Java Replace Unicode Characters in a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41667632/java-replace-unicode-characters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution given by **Jeff Potts** will be perfect .
But i had a situation where i was using file name in diffrent project where i wont  use org.alfresco related jars

I had to take all those dependencies to use for a simple file decoding 
So i used java native methods which uses regex to parse the file name and decode it,which gave me the perfect solution which was same from using

```
ISO9075.decode(test);
```

This is the code which can be used

```
 public String decode_FileName(String fileName) {
        System.out.println("fileName : " + fileName);
        String decodedfileName = fileName;
        String temp = "";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\_x(.*?)\\_").matcher(decodedfileName); //rejex which matches _x0020_ kind of charectors
        List<String> unicodeChars = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (m.find()) {
            unicodeChars.add(m.group(1));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < unicodeChars.size(); i++) {
            temp = unicodeChars.get(i);
            if (isInteger(temp)) {
                String replace_char = String.valueOf(((char) Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(temp), 16)));//converting  
                decodedfileName = decodedfileName.replace("_x" + temp + "_", replace_char);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Decoded FileName :" + decodedfileName);
        return decodedfileName;
    }
```

And use this small java util to know Is integer

```
public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(s);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So the above code works as simple as this :

Example :

**0028 Left parenthesis U+0028**  You can see in the link 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

```
String replace_char = String.valueOf(((char) Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf("0028"), 16)));
        System.out.println(replace_char);
```

This code gives output : `(`  which is a Left parenthesis

This is what the logic i have used in my java program.

The above program will give results same as `ISO9075.decode(test)`

```
Output :

fileName : ABC1X_x0020_0400_x0020_0109-_x0028_1-2_x0029__v2.pdf
Decoded FileName :ABC1X 0400 0109-(1-2)_v2.pdf
```

Comment: I am using the service outside the project So this code works perfect for me

Answer (score 2):

In the org.alfresco.util package you will find a class called ISO9075. You can use it to encode and decode strings according to that spec. For example:

```
    String test = "ABC1X_x0020_0400_x0020_0109-_x0028_1-2_x0029__v2.pdf";
    String out = ISO9075.decode(test);
    System.out.println(out);
```

Returns:

```
    ABC1X 0400 0109-(1-2)_v2.pdf
```

If you want to see what it does behind the scenes, look at the source.